# Is it possible to send file and data in same POST request using python request library?

Tags: python, django, rest, post, python-requests

I want to send file as well as data in same POST request. is it possible?

I tried with python request library but ended up receiving either file or data but not both at the same time.

```
import requests

files = {
    'upload_file': open('creds.txt','rb')
}
data = {
    "collection_name": "detete-test-1",
    "source": {
        "data": {
            "data1": "some random string"
        }
    }
}

url = 'http://localhost:8000/v1/source/test'
r = requests.post(url, json=data, files=files)
```

Tried above code but i was just receiving ImMemoryUploadedFile object in django not the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Where do you want to read the data? The `print(r)` that you do is the complete response object from that request.

Anyway, what you can do in your django view is the following:

```
def example_view(request):
   my_file = request.FILES.get('upload_file')
   file_contents = my_file.read()
```